# Creating a dummy user for Default Record Ownership

Tags: user, ownership

I am looking to create a test user that will be assigned to the automated ownership settings (default lead owner, default case owner, records created by community users). We already have a similar "Integration User" who we use for the API.  Other than a potential data skew, is it ok to create a second test user to assign records to?

Comment: we use a headless user for similar items and find it to be best practice. Assignment rules if properly constructed will take care of record ownership to real users.  Note we do this in PROD and don't call it a "test" user

Comment: @cropredy thank you, I knew there was a better term than test user, just couldn't remember it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every org I have been involved with (admittedly EE or UE orgs), we established as best practice a headless user for:

- Default case owner (Support Settings)
- Default lead owner (Lead Settings)
- Default owner for Community-created cases

This headless user(s), by not being tied to a real person, meant that if the person left, we didn't have to change config as well or leave long-gone real people as frozen users. How many headless users we created depends on traceability goals.

We also defined a distro list that Apex exception emails were sent to (never a specific user)

Proper assignment rules should assign objects to real users and the default headless user is really a backstop.

We also tend to run most scheduled Apex jobs under a headless user to do two things:

- Show traceability on record DML to an automated process rather than some "real" user who didn't really do the DML via some direct UX action.
- Avoid the issues of deactivating users associated to scheduled processes that suddenly stop running